# Authenticate aws to salesforce and access api endpoint

Tags: amazon-aws

I have an aws lambda that when called needs to pass a json object to a SFDC endpoint. I’d like to avoid using the jForce library to handle authentication as I don’t want to set username and password in code if possible. Does anyone have any references or recommendations on how to authenticate a request from aws to an SFDC api endpoint without first being logged into salesforce? I realize a connected app is an option just interested to see if there are other implementations.

Comment: https://github.com/developerforce/iotconnectors/wiki/AWSPlatformEvents-JWT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For server to server authentication and authorization a connected app with the [JWT based oauth flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) is good option .

You will need to register a certificate and then you can use that as a private key.

The other option is to use [Certificate Based Authentication](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_certificate_based_auth_config.htm&type=5) .You will need to have org admin turn on this feature to leverage this .